# style attribute textColorPrimary not found

Tags: android

I'd like to change the color of the text in `textColorPrimary` attribute in styles.xml

```
<item name="textColorPrimary">#FFEB3B</item>
```

> Error:error: style attribute 'attr/textColorPrimary (aka com.example.android.christmasgifts:attr/textColorPrimary)' not found.

Complete error below
[image]

Answer (score 11):

I had the same trouble. 
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/textColorPrimary (aka ...../textColorPrimary)' not found.

Whole information, which is about design, is in values.xml.

I changed from **textColorPrimary** to **android:textColorPrimary** and it works now . :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think it's missing the prefix android:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFEB3B</item>
```

Comment: I tried it. Still nothing. I don't have any error BUT the color is NOT changing. But thanks for your reply

Comment: Usually I use the attribute `android:textColor` for changing the text color... Try with that.

Answer (score 0):

Dalla95's answer is correct, but your case is not error but mine error. To address this, you should specify android: for textColorPrimary, please check code below:

```
<style name="ToolbarThemeDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And for the Color not changing maybe you use it wrong.
you should call your theme by :

```
app:theme="@style/ToolbarThemeDemo"
```

not below:

```
style="@style/ToolbarThemeDemo"
```